# Gitkraken not working Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 and I installed Gitkraken using snap. When opening Gitkraken via the terminal, a windows pops up, but closes immediatly without printing any messages in the terminal. I tried installing gitkraken via the software shop, and using the tar.gz, but the same issue occured. Does anybody else have the same problem? If so how did you fix it?

Kind regards

Comment: This sounds a bit like [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1944468) bug, but I'm not sure which flavours of Ubuntu 22.04 it affects. It seems to affect at least those using KDE.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. I've had issues with GitKraken, Atom, and Etcher (all Electron apps). I have been successful getting Atom and Etcher to run on a fresh image of 22.04 but neither will run on the image upgraded from 21.10.  Gitkraken doesn't run at all on either image.  I think it is due to the weird way that gitkraken starts up but not sure.  See my post askubuntu.com/questions/1405561/…

Comment: Install from the Snap Store, it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the previous answer, here is a step by step instruction set to get open SSL 1.1.1 libs on Ubuntu 22.04:

Get build tools:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall zlib1g-dev -y
```

Make working dir:

```
mkdir openssl-v1.1.1 && cd openssl-v1.1.1
```

Get Open SSL 1.1.1 latest version:

```
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1o.tar.gz
tar -xvzf openssl-1.1.1o.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.1.1o
```

Configure build:

```
chmod +x ./config
./config
```

Build it (j = ncores)

```
make -j 4
```

Test it:

```
make test
```

If everything works, move the libs to your local lib.

```
sudo mv libssl.so.1.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
sudo mv libcrypto.so.1.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

Now GitKraken from the terminal should launch:

```
gitkraken
```

The snap is always a few versions behind the .deb, and you only have to build open SSL once on 24.04, then all subsequent .deb installs will work as normal.

Comment: This worked, thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

in my case was necessary run : `sudo kill -9 {PID}` and open the GitkKraken again.

I believe it was running what I had installed manually before, it was necessary to kill the process in hand and open the version installed by snap.

Answer (score 0):

When I run gitkraken from the terminal, it logs 'build/Debug/nodegit.node' is not found.

It turns out the nodegit.node requires `openssl v1`. Specifically, it needs two files, `libcrypto.so.1.1 and libssl.so.1.1`.

By default ubuntu 22.04 use openssl v3 and there is not openssl v1 in the apt repository. So I compiled the latest openssl v1 manually and configured `a custom install prefix` just in case it may cause
conflicts in the future, then symbolic link these two files to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu.

[openssl v1 github release page](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/releases/tag/OpenSSL_1_1_1o)