# Multiple app failures on 22.04 LTS

Tags: apt, upgrade, 22.04

***UPDATE***
I changed the title because this has nothing to do with upgrading from 22.10.  I just created an fresh image installing from the 22.04 LTS live image and then installed the *deb packages.  The exact same behavior happens there.  This is an issue with 22.04 LTS; not sure how 22.04 LTS got to release when some pretty common apps like **atom** and **gitkraken** do not install/work.  The **etcher** AppImage does work on the fresh install.

***ORIGINAL POST***
I just now upgraded from 21.10 to 22.04 LTS.  I performed the upgrade via `do-release-upgrade`.  Following are now failing after working withtout issue on 21.10:

**balenaEtcher-1.7.7-x64.AppImage** `Error: /tmp/.mount_balenaGlYYUI/balena-etcher-electron: line 10:  3717 Trace/breakpoint trap   (core dumped) "${script_dir}"/balena-etcher-electron.bin "$@"`
(Likely related: [AppImages won't open on Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404349/appimages-wont-open-on-ubuntu-22-04).  See also [Gitkraken not working Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405003/gitkraken-not-working-ubuntu-22-04) and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1944468)

**gitkraken**: Starts but then immediately closes; no error reported.  I did `sudo apt remove gitkraken`.  Downloaded new .deb package from the site and installed via `sudo apt install ./gitkraken-amd64.deb`.  The install reported this error: `N: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/home/<user>/Downloads/atom-amd64.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)`.  Same behavior; opens and immediately closes.

**atom**: Starts but them immediately closes.  After the first open, it prompted with an error which I agreed to send.  I did `sudo apt remove atom` which removed it.  Downloaded new .deb package from the site and installed via `sudo apt install ./atom-amd64.deb`.  The install reported this error: `N: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/home/<user>/Downloads/atom-amd64.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)`.  Same behavior; opens and immediately closes.

For context, the **brave** browser opens and works fine.

I ran `atom` at the command line and got this:

```
~$ atom
~$ /usr/bin/atom: line 195:  2803 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) nohup "$ATOM_PATH" --executed-from="$(pwd)" --pid=$$ "$@" > "$ATOM_HOME/nohup.out" 2>&1
[2803:0429/094123.175655:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(439)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
(node:2862) Electron: Loading non-context-aware native module in renderer: '/usr/share/atom/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/superstring/build/Release/superstring.node'. This is deprecated, see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397.
(node:2862) Electron: Loading non-context-aware native module in renderer: '/usr/share/atom/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/pathwatcher/build/Release/pathwatcher.node'. This is deprecated, see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397.
--2022-04-29 09:41:23--  https://atom.io/crash_reports
Resolving atom.io (atom.io)... 20.119.16.4
Connecting to atom.io (atom.io)|20.119.16.4|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 204 No Content
2022-04-29 09:41:24 (0.00 B/s) - ‘/dev/fd/4’ saved [0]


Unexpected crash report id length
Failed to get crash dump id.
Report Id: 
--2022-04-29 09:41:24--  https://atom.io/crash_reports
Resolving atom.io (atom.io)... 20.119.16.4
Connecting to atom.io (atom.io)|20.119.16.4|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 204 No Content
2022-04-29 09:41:25 (0.00 B/s) - ‘/dev/fd/4’ saved [0]


Unexpected crash report id length
Failed to get crash dump id.
Report Id:
```

**UPDATE**
I left this image as it is (so we can figure out what is happening?) and installed in a different partition of the same system a fresh image of impish 21.10 (the level on which I had been working successfully).  I then installed **atom**, **gitkraken**, and add the **etcher** AppImage.  All installed successfully and run fine.

Note that, when installing both **atom** and **gitkraken** I received the same error I listed above (`N: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/home/<user>/Downloads/atom-amd64.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)`) -- so that doesn't seem to be related.  They run fine despite this error.

Comment: I've seen other people with this error. Do try a few things: 1) try installing the atom .deb package with "sudo dpkg -i pathToYourDownloadedDebFile". 2) if that still doesn't work, uninstall then install via flatpak (https://flathub.org/apps/details/io.atom.Atom). Do any of those work?

Comment: I tried #1.  This resulted in the same behavior.  Regarding #2, this is a minimal build system that I'd prefer to not add additional packages.  I do not currently have flatpak builder installed.  Understand that, my purpose in this post is about getting it to run in the same way as it did before (i.e., via apt) and notifying someone of these issues rather than to find a new way to get these running.

Comment: Well, I'm intrigued. Will follow the question in case you figure it out (or someone with more experience writes an answer).

Comment: You said you're not sure how 22.04 was released with some apps not functioning, but Atom works for me on 22.04 (both flatpak and the official deb file). I haven't tried GitKraken, but I don't expect I'll have trouble (*will* try to see if I can reproduce your error).

Comment: @CeciliaLopes  Thanks for confirming it is working for you; that it's unique me is more comforting -- though I have no idea why it is failing.  This is with the currently available deb versions of both atom and gitkraken.

Comment: @CeciliaLopes I just tried this on an entirely different system running a fresh install of 22.04 LTS.  Atom installed and works fine.  Gitkraken installed but exhibits the same behavior as I saw on the other system.  Something strange happening here.

Comment: Someone else experiencing this... https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405003/gitkraken-not-working-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: Gitkraken issue can be temporaly fixed: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403619/mongodb-install-fails-on-ubuntu-22-04-depends-on-libssl1-1-but-it-is-not-insta/1403683#1403683

Answer (score 2):

If you're running NVIDIA drivers (510 or 470 versions), this may be the cause of the issue. If you happen to have hybrid graphics and the option to use Intel graphics exclusively, try enabling that.

For me, this fixed the problem I was experiencing with a number of apps after installing 22.04, including `Balena Etcher`, `PlexAmp`, `Atom`, `Zoom`, and others that were installed via multiple means (AppImage's, .deb files, APT).

Comment: Thanks, my system is using those drivers.  I wondered if it might be related as I found that I did not have issues* on a different system.  However, I found GitKraken will not run on 22.04 on any system I've tried.  Do you use it and, if so, are you using it successfully?  I'll try going back to the Xorg drivers when I get back to that system.

Comment: @AdvApp: are you running GitKraken via the Snap or did you install it with the .deb?

Comment: As noted in the original post, "installed the *deb packages."

Comment: When debugging, I was able to replicate the issue on my Intel integrated graphics as well, and GitKraken produces the following error: `libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so init failed`.

@AdvApp: are you running an i9 processor as well?

Comment: Running on AMD Ryzen 7 3700X.  But I've also tried running GitKraken on my Chromebook running 22.04 LTS and it exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: @AdvApp I know this isn't a true solution to the issues happening with GitKraken's .deb package on 22.04, but I was able to get it worked by using the [official Flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.axosoft.GitKraken).

Comment: It would be helpful to know: Does the flatpak version "just work" once installed?  Or did you have to tweak it?

Comment: @AdvApp for me it "just worked" after I first removed and purged the Debian package and then installed the Flatpak.

Comment: ClickUp was failing in my case, an electron app distributed as AppImage. I got it working appending ` --no-sandbox` to the command.

Comment: As for Atom. See my comments at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405511/failure-to-launch-atom-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts

Answer (score 1):

not a proper answer, but snap version works good

also idea:
using wayland or gdm?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Atom. It worked after uninstalling it `sudo apt purge atom` and installing it with snap `sudo snap install atom --classic`

Answer (score 0):

Install gitkraken from the snap store, it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I completely removed gitkraken and installed the lastest v8.9.1.  This installs successfully (including creating the favorite icon) and launches correctly without error.